# What is a linear equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, definition

How do we define the linear equation? I mean, it looks like a polynomials with degree one but I'm not sure if $ax+by+c=0$ is a linear equation if $a=b=0$?

Comment: $ax+by+c=0$ is a linear equation, if $a,b,c$ are real numbers

Comment: $a, b, c$ need not be real, they just need to be constants in the ring where your solutions live.  Complex numbers and elements of finite fields, for example, are fine.  Though complex numbers may be, and finite fields certainly are, beyond where the OP likely is in their studies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A linear equation is any equation that can be written in the form
$$a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + \cdots + a_nx_n = b$$
where $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$, and $b$ are constants and $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ are variables without using multiplication or division to get it there.

So $ax + by + c = 0$ can be turned into $ax + by = -c$ and hence is linear.  But $ax^2 + bxy + cx = 0$ needs division in order to turn it into $ax + by = -c$ (and that division changes the solutions) so it is not linear.  The end result, as you point out, is that a linear equation is any equation given by a polynomial of degree *at most* 1.

The number of variables, $n$, is allowed to be zero if you like, as are all the constants $a_i$ and the constant $b$ ($0 = 0$ is linear).  So in sum: yes, $ax + by + c = 0$ is linear even if $a = b = 0$.