# How is $\frac{-7y}{x}+\frac{1}{x}=1$ a Linear equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

My book says:

"Observe that a linear equation does not involve any products or roots of variables. All
variables occur only to the first power and do not appear, for example, as arguments of
trigonometric, logarithmic, or exponential functions."

But in the equation $-7\frac{y}{x}+\frac{1}{x}=1$ the variable $x$ has a power of $-1$ and $\frac{y}{x}$ is also present which does not satisfy the conditions mentioned in my book.

I also looked at [another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1031250/what-is-a-linear-equation) which says:

"A linear equation is any equation that can be written in the form
$$a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + \cdots + a_nx_n = b$$
where $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$, and $b$ are constants and $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ are variables without using multiplication or division to get it there."

To convert $-7\frac{y}{x}+\frac{1}{x}=1$ in the form $a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + \cdots + a_nx_n = b$ we clearly require multiplication, so can you please explain what am  I missing here?

Comment: _"we clearly require multiplication"_ - What about $\displaystyle{\dfrac{x^2 + 4x + 4}{x + 2}}$?

Comment: You shouldn't write the question as $-7\frac{y}{x}+\frac{1}{x}=1$ , but as $\frac{-7y}{x} + \frac{1}{x} = 1$, as in the former, the first term may be interpreted as a mixed fraction. Or else weite it as $-7\cdot\frac{y}{x}...$

Comment: It is a linear equation *in $y$,* that is when we treat $x$ as a constant or parameter instead of a variable; rename $x$ to $a$ if you prefer.

Comment: Linear could mean that the powers of the variables involved are all equal to one.

Answer (score 5):

Your equation has a constraint $x\not=0$. Notice that we can re-write the equation as $$\frac{-7y+1}{x}=1,$$since we are *adding homogeneous fractions*.  Then, we have $$-7y+1=x$$ or equivalently $$(1)\cdot y+\left(\frac{1}{7}\right)x=\frac{1}{7}$$which is a linear equation.

Comment: I don't understand your point, I can provide more details if anyone thinks it's missing.

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't looks like it is a linear equation, the thing is, the author of the book has wrote it such like that, that it doesn't looks like linear equation, but in maths we've powers to make changes in equation without affecting original equation you know it lol.

what I meant is basically we need to simplify it.

$$\frac{-7y}{x} + \frac{1}{x} = 1
\\ \frac{-7y + 1}{x} = 1
\\ -7y + 1 = x
\\ x + 7y = 1$$

and now it looks like linear equation right.